Excel VBA delete shapes with duplicate names
My objective is to delete all shapes with duplicate names by name, and keep only one. (so names of remaining shapes are unique.)
Based on the below link, names in Excel VBA is not unique.
https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/vba-macros/guides/shapes/shapes/#:~:text=Shape%20names%20are%20a%20bit,that%20you've%20created%20programmatically.
I checked below VBA code, if there are multiple CheckBox1 in ActiveSheet, only 1 CheckBox1 would be deleted.
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("CheckBox1")).Delete
How can I delete all CheckBox1 and keep only 1? Thank you!


For Each iterates all shapes on active sheet
Using Dictionary to store the unique list of shapes' name

Sub RemoveDupShp()
    Dim Shp As Shape, oDic
    Set oDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Not oDic.Exists(Shp.Name) Then
            oDic.Add Shp.Name, Empty
        Else
            Shp.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub

